# Symfony2 using google recaptcha with Genemu Captcha

Tags: symfony, bundle, recaptcha

I working with Symfony 2.7.9 and used the bundle MremiContactBundle. now, I want to use the google recaptcha, but i had the problem that form show the google recaptcha only show by image and number,  and i need  show google recaptcha to choose "I´m not Robot". 
I need help. 
Thank you

Comment: Do you mean symfony *2.8* instead of *2.9*

Comment: Sorry, I meant to version 2.7.9